# How to create peewee database at custom path

Tags: python, sqlite, django-models, peewee

I'm trying to create a database at a certain path, but I cannot figure out how to do so because I need to reference the created database in the Meta

I'm trying to create the database something like this:

```
class Domain(Model):
    ...

    class Meta:
        database = db

...

def create_database(path: str, start_block: int):
    db = SqliteDatabase(os.path.join(path, "db"))

    db.create_tables([Domain, Event, State])

    if State.select().count() == 0:
        State.create(height=start_block)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is covered in the documentation:

- http://docs.peewee-orm.com/en/latest/peewee/database.html#run-time-database-configuration
- http://docs.peewee-orm.com/en/latest/peewee/database.html#dynamically-defining-a-database
- http://docs.peewee-orm.com/en/latest/peewee/database.html#setting-the-database-at-run-time